# Simple C++ address / pointer clarification

Tags: c++

Is the first temp assignment (1) useless (well, other than declaring a type)?  I'm thinking the second assignment is just over-writing temp's pointer to `key_record`.

```
   void store_key( const key_data& key )
   {
      owallet_key_record key_record = ...
      key_data& temp = *key_record;  // 1
      temp = key;
   }
```

EDIT: reference, https://github.com/BitShares/bitshares/blob/v0.4.28-dev1/libraries/wallet/wallet_db.cpp#L555-L556

Note, `temp` is not used again.  Also, this technique is used several times in the file in this same pattern so it must be intentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thoughts are correct, but I wouldn't characterize the reference declaration as "useless".

Depending on what else is going on in the store_key() method, this kind of a reference declaration is often used for clarity, and maybe to make frequent usage of the referenced object more clear, and readable.

And, even if not, you should leave code optimization to the compiler. If a temporary reference results in clearer, easier to understand code, that's good enough reason on its own. Let the compiler worry about optimizing away unneeded temporaries.

Comment: Like a cast?  `key_data& key` is also a valid `owallet_key_record`

Comment: A BitShares developer is confirming, "it’s inherited, thus the need for an explicit cast" and "need to explicitly cast it via “(key_data&)*key_record = key”".

Answer (score 1):

<sub>At the time of this answer, the definition of `owallet_key_record` is not available. To be honest, I don't really care what it is defined as, since your question is really asking for a hypothetical situation where this "idiom" may make sense. If you want to know why it makes sense for this particular source code, then this would not be the right answer for you (but still maybe useful to someone else).</sub>

It may be the case that the type `*owallet_key_record` results in a type that defines its own assignment operator, but for which there is a conversion operator to a `key_data &`.

So, if for example:

```
struct owallet_key_record {
    key_data k;
    struct deref {
        owallet_key_record *r;
        ~deref () { r->release(); }
        deref (owallet_key_record *x) : r(x) { r->acquire(); }
        deref (const deref &d) : r(d.r) { r->acquire(); }
        deref & operator = (deref d) { std::swap(r, d.r); return *this; }
        operator key_data & () { return r->key(); }
    };
    deref operator * () { return this; }
    key_data & key () { return k; }
    void acquire () {}
    void release () {}
};
```

Then the following will fail:

```
owallet_key_record key_record /*= ...*/;
*key_record = key;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong. The first "assignment" is in fact not an assignment. It initializes a reference.

References cannot be re-initialized. The second `=` is a true assignment. It changes `*key_record`, the object referenced by `temp`.

A competent C++ programmer would just write `*key_record = key`, though. The reference just names the result of `*key_record`, and `temp` is not a helpful name at all.

Comment: This makes sense.. trust me, they are very competent just busy ;)